# Any way to change icons of Chrome shortcuts pinned to taskbar? (Windows 10)

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons, desktop-customization

I have a bunch of websites "saved as shortcuts" from Chrome, and pinned to taskbar.

But I would like to customize the taskbar icons, e.g., to distinguish Outlook Mail from Calendar:

[image]

How do I do this on Windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

This can be done as follows:

1. Right-click on the taskbar pinned item and click **Unpin from Taskbar**
2. The original shortcut should now be on your desktop. If not, recreate it by going to the site in Chrome, clicking the three vertical dots in the top right, then **More tools** and then **Create shortcut...**
3. Right-click on the shortcut that Chrome created and click Properties
4. Click the Shortcut tab and then ***Change Icon...*** [image]
5. Click Browse and select the icon you want, then OK and OK
6. The icon will now change to the new one you selected [image]
7. Right-click the icon on the desktop and click **Pin to Taskbar** and it'll be on the taskbar with your new icon [image: Taskbar]